# SQL - Max dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Essentially I want to pull the highest [effective date] for each [typecode] in the dataset... this

```
HIC         CODE PROVIDER DATE                   TYPECODE EFFECTIVE DATE
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    0     2014-10-10 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    0     2015-01-30 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    1     2015-01-23 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    1     2015-02-06 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    2     2015-02-06 00:00:00.000
```

to look like this:

```
HIC         CODE PROVIDER DATE                   TYPECODE EFFECTIVE DATE
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    0     2015-01-30 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    1     2015-02-06 00:00:00.000
028207696D  10   347330  2014-09-15 00:00:00.000    2     2015-02-06 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: You should always provide what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT HIC,CODE,PROVIDER DATE,TypeCode,MAX([Effective Date])[Effective Date]
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY HIC,CODE,PROVIDER DATE,TypeCode
```